# How to configure Excel and SharePoint to access remote databases

Tags: excel-services, excel

I am using Excel to render data stored in a PostgresQL database elsewhere on our network.  In general, the rendering works.  However, I haven't been able to get the document to automatically update/refresh data from the data source when users view the page.

The Excel data source is a DSN.  I'm assuming the ODBC drivers and DSN would need to be installed on the SharePoint server, but I suspect more than this has to be done.

Anybody know the steps involved ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue getting data from a MSSQL database. Have you made any progress on this since March?

Comment: @SubmittedDenied - No.  I manually update the document periodically.  We've recently upgraded to SharePoint 2010, but haven't reexplored the issue.  If you find a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Excel Services in SharePoint Server 2010 to render the workbook? If so, in the service application, you set upt he trusted locations to store the excel workbooks. In the settings for each trusted location, there's an option to automatically refresh connections in the workbook.

Comment: I've yet to go back to the issues since the 2010 upgrade.  It's a spreadsheet that only gets reviewed once or twice a month.  Under the older version, we had put the workbook into a trusted location.